# Angular Directive isn't updating google map values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with the name "myMap" which is using to add google map.
When I am trying to update longitude and latitude again different location using my controller function, it doesn't updating directive value.same map is showing.

Here is my Directive:

```
directive('myMap', function () {
    // directive link function
    var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var map, infoWindow;
        var markers = [];

        // map config
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.latitude, attrs.longitude),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        };

        // init the map
        function initMap() {
            if (map === void 0) {
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
            }
        }

        // place a marker
        function setMarker(map, position, title, content) {
            var marker;
            var markerOptions = {
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: title,
                icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.Bounce

            };

            marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
            markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                // close window if not undefined
                if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                    infoWindow.close();
                }
                // create new window
                var infoWindowOptions = {
                    content: content
                };
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        // show the map and place some markers
        initMap();

        setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.latitude, attrs.longitude), attrs.restname, attrs.address);

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
});
```

After that I am calling this directive from my HTML. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="gmaps"   my-map="" latitude="{{home.latitude}}" longitude="{{home.longitude}}"></div>
```

I am stuck with this. I used different approaches but it doesn't work in my case.
How to check different changing in parameters of directive so that I can analyse updating values of longitude and latitude?
Kindly Help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add watcher in your directive.

```
 attrs.$observe("value", function (data) {},true);
```

It observe the change in parameters of directive and update them when it will be changed.
in your case it will be

```
lahorefoodsWebSiteModule.directive('myMap', function () {
// directive link function
var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe("latitude", function (latitude) {
        //This gets called when data changes.

    var map, infoWindow;
    var markers = [];

    // map config
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.latitude, attrs.longitude),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    };

    // init the map
    function initMap() {
        if (map === void 0) {
            map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
        }
    }

    // place a marker
    function setMarker(map, position, title, content) {
        var marker;
        var markerOptions = {
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.Bounce

        };

        marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            // close window if not undefined
            if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                infoWindow.close();
            }
            // create new window
            var infoWindowOptions = {
                content: content
            };
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    // show the map and place some markers
    initMap();

    setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.latitude, attrs.longitude), attrs.restname, attrs.address);
    },true);
};

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: link
};
```

});

Html code will be same.Hopefully it will resolve your issue.